# How do build GNOME apps of a SLES15 machine with few/no GNOME development libs?

Tags: gnome, compiling, dependencies

I want to build a GNOME-ish app on a SLES15 machine I'm working on. I can download the source, but the app relies on multiple GNOME-related libraries - for which I only have the `libfoo` packages, not `libfoo-dev` packagesd - which seem to be missing from the distribution altogether; for other libraries - the distribution's version is too low. Specific example:

```
        gthread-2.0 >= 2.38
        glib-2.0 >= 2.38
        gobject-2.0 >= 2.38
        gmodule-2.0 >= 2.38
        gio-2.0 >= 2.38
        gio-unix-2.0 >= 2.38
        gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 0.10.1
        libgit2-glib-1.0 >= 0.25.0
        libgit2-glib-1.0 < 0.26.0
        gtk+-3.0 >= 3.20.0
        gtksourceview-3.0 >= 3.10
        gsettings-desktop-schemas
        gee-0.8
        libsoup-2.4
        libsecret-1
```

How can I get my dependencies and build the package (other than going one-by-one recursively)?